# GetElementsByXpath in WebBrowser Document?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

**Please Help me :`(**

> hi friends i tried for find a way for GetElementsBy Xpath from a
>   WebSite and show in textbox...! I use WebBrowser Class in Project !!

[image]

Thank u so much

Comment: Looks like you are using selenium, if it is the case update the tags to get correct attention.

Answer (score 0):

Using [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack):

```
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.stackoverflow.com");

var txt = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/head/title").InnerText;
```